# Docker compose taking too long

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a lot of projects in one solution in visual studio 2019 in a micro service architecture with Docker. now i have a docker-compose.yml file. it seems to be taking too long to build even one image and by taking too long i mean like more than an hour.

```
services:
  nosql.data:
    image: mongo

  mongo1:
    image: mongo
    hostname: mongo1
    container_name: mongo1
    command: "--replSet rs0"

  mongo2:
    image: mongo
    hostname: mongo2
    container_name: mongo2
    command: "--replSet rs0"

  mongo3:
    image: mongo
    hostname: mongo3
    container_name: mongo3
    command: "--replSet rs0"

  mysql.data: 
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysql.data

  rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq:management
    container_name: rabbit

  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.2.0
    container_name: es01
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata01:/elasticsearch/data

  es02:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.2.0
    container_name: es02
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata02:/elasticsearch/data

  cnx.useraccessmanagement.api:
    image: ${REGISTRY:}/useraccessmanagement.api:${PLATFORM:-linux}-${TAG:-latest}
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/Services/Program2/Dockerfile 
    depends_on:
       - nosql.data
       - mysql.data
       - rabbit

  cnx.identity.api:
    image: ${REGISTRY:}/identity.api:${PLATFORM:-linux}-${TAG:-latest}
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/Services/Program1/Dockerfile

  cnx.apigateway:
    image: ${REGISTRY:}/apigateway:${PLATFORM:-linux}-${TAG:-latest}
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/ApiGateway/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - identity.api
      - nosql.data
      - mysql.data
      - rabbit 

volumes:
  esdata01:
    driver: local
  esdata02:
    driver: local
```

the project file size is almost 1gb and in terms of the build context set in this docker compose file, does it matter when it comes to affecting the build time? if so, what could be done for this to be optimized?

Comment: Have you tried using a [.dockerignore file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file)?

Comment: i do have a docker ignore file. but forgive me it's just pretty basic. i am just relatively new to docker so everything was created by people who started the project and not me. @bellackn

Comment: Ok, so the (unnecessary) big files are ignored already? Good, so what's the exact step where the build process takes too long? Could you add some output to your question?

Comment: @bellackn i already did, it's okay now, i used to do that before but got overwritten when i pulled from git. but one thing, how can i accomplish this via build context? the directory i added to be ignored is needed for another image. won't it be a problem if i'm going to build that image with all the others?